# What prevents a browser from loading 2 long running PHP scripts concurrently from the same domain?

Tags: php, configuration

There appears to be a limit on the number of concurrent scripts for a php session. I say session and not IP / client because I can start up another browser and load the second script. Is there a parameter limiting to one concurrent script?

You have to wait for one to complete before the other one starts loading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default session handler uses files, and will lock the session file for the duration of the request. If you have a long-running script, then you should force it to relinquish the session lock by doing a `session_write_close()` before entering the "long running" part of the script.

You can always re-open the session with `session_start()` again later on, if you need to modify session data after the long-running portion completes.

Comment: Interesting, is there a way to avoid locking up the session without changing code. Something in php.ini perhaps?

Comment: Though I realize that could lead to some painful race conditions.

Comment: No. it's by design - if the session's not locked, then multiple parallel requests will stomp on the file. Changing the code is minor - if your long running script doesn't change session data during/after the long-running part, then closing the session will have no effect. The $_SESSION variable will still be there and usable, just that any changes made to it won't be written out when the script exits.